# Your point being?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase, phrase-request, proverb

How would you translate "your point being?".

Best thing I can come up with is "Und?". But that only works if the context is there. Is there some more "correct" translation?

Answer (score 17):

In colloquial it's absolutely fine to say "Und?" which may sound rude though. A more friendly way to ask is:

> Worauf willst du hinaus?

Comment: I think "Und?" has pretty much the same connotations as "Your point being?" (which I wouldn't classify as particularly nice either).

Answer (score 10):

Ich würde das so spontan mit

> "Was wollen Sie/willst du damit sagen?"

übersetzen. Ich bin mir allerdings auch nicht sicher ob das in allen Zusammenhängen funktioniert.

"Und?" oder "Na und?" passen auch an manchen Stellen..

Comment: "Und weiter?" würde auch oft gehen.

Comment: Inzwischen hat auch "So -- what?" allerorts Eingang gefunden.

Answer (score 6):

> Und was möchtest du damit sagen?
>   Und was möchten Sie damit ausdrücken?

sind sehr viel höflicher als '*Na und?*'.

Beide sind jedoch korrekt.

Comment: "Das heißt?" ist eine etwas weniger höfliche Form die ich auch oft höre/sage.

Answer (score 0):

Simply "Wie bitte?" or "Bitte?" would work also, as you just want your conversational partner to explain his point more further. 
The old exalted phrase "wie meinen?" could also fit, but would sound strange nowadays.

Comment: "[Wie] bitte?" klingt nach "das habe ich (akustisch) nicht verstanden". Das ist nicht die Bedeutung von "your point being?"

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively one could say

> Worum geht es dir?
>   Um was geht es dir?